# What Firewall Rules for Audit Collection Service in SCOM 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall, scom

What Firewall Ports or Rules do I have to Configure, to enable the Forwarders to Connect to the ACS Collector?

When the Firewall on Collector is `enabled`, no Forwarder `can connect` to the Collector, When the Firewall on Collector is `disabled`, the Forwarders `cannot connect` to the Collector.

The Event View displays events saying: Audit Forwarder connceted on Port: `51408`
the next server is connecting on Port `19904`

Is it possible to set `static Ports`?

Im Using Windows Server 2012R2 on all Servers, Im Using System Center Operations Manager 2012,

Comment: Are the forwarder and collector in the same domain?

Comment: yes, the are in the same domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Microsoft says  - Because of the limited communication between an ACS forwarder and an ACS collector you only need to open the inbound TCP port 51909 on a firewall to enable an ACS forwarder, separated from your network by a firewall, to reach the ACS collector.

You can check if default port is not changed from 51909:

1. On the ACS Collector server run regedit
2. Go to HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\AdtServer\Parameters
3. Check key named AdtAgentPort and its value (should be 51909)

Comment: default port has not changed. Firewall port `51909` open now on collector. Still no connection. Also Im getting errors(id: 4680 and id: 4618). The Collector cannot connect to the database. Im `not getting` those errors, if the firewall `allows all inbound ports` on collector server.

Comment: well, after opening those ports, i did a reboot of the collector machine. this solved my issue.